# jQuery Mobile form validation on login page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-mobile

I have been searching for a way to validate the forms on my login page. I found a promising solution here on stackoverflow with an accompanying JSFiddle.

I didnt like exactly how he/she styled it so I just put what i thought to be important in.

What happens now is that instead of just going to the next page (like it used to do) it just...refreshes the page (at least that is what appears to happen).

Here is my HTML and Js that I used

```
<form id="form1" name="ff1">

    <p class="numba1"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" 
style="border: 1px solid grey !important; background:#FFF8E6; box-
shadow: none !important; border: none;" id="fremail"  data-wrapper-
class="ui-custom" placeholder="Email"></p>

    <p class="numba2"><input type="password" name="password" 
id="password" style=" border: 1px solid grey !important; background-
color:#FFF8E6; text-shadow: none; box-shadow: none !important; 
border: none;" value="" data-wrapper-class="ui-custom" 
placeholder="Password"></p>


  <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" id="submit"  />

  </form>

 $('#form1').validate({
 rules: {

    email: {
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        required: true
    }
 },
 messages: {

    email: {
        required: "Please enter your last name."
    },
    password: {
        required: "Please enter your email."
    }
 },
 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parent().prev());
 },
 submitHandler: function (form) {
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#homePage', {
        reload: false
    });
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: If you are still looking for a solution, you may want to post more code?  It appears to me that there is more to this page than just the html you posted.  Also, what other StackOverflow and JSFiddle did you like? a link or two may help.

Comment: I got help from a teacher at my school and the code was much simpler than I was thinking. Thank you for your continued interest though.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to handle the POST request server side and serve a different page or redirect when you do the authentication check based on login success or failure.

As far as it showing up the same page, if you need the POST to go to a different place you need to add the **action** attribute and specify a url.

```
<form action="/login" id="form1" name="ff1" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

Comment: The same effect of the page being refreshed or reloading still occurs